# How is the method of stationary phase used?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, integration, approximations

Many path integrals involve complex exponentials
that are highly oscillatory.
These integrals can often be solved using the method of stationary phase.
Please explain how to use the method of stationary phase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method of stationary phase can be used to solve
integrals of the form
$$
I=\int_a^b f(x)e^{i\lambda g(x)}\,dx
$$

where $\lambda\gg1$.
The solution is
$$
I\approx e^{i\pi\operatorname{sgn}(g''(c))/4}
\biggl(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda|g''(c)|}\biggr)^{1/2}
f(c)e^{i\lambda g(c)}
$$

where $c$ is the critical point such that
$$
g'(c)=0
$$

For $\operatorname{sgn}(g''(c))=1$ the solution
can be written more simply as
$$
I\approx
\biggl(\frac{2\pi i}{\lambda|g''(c)|}\biggr)^{1/2}
f(c)e^{i\lambda g(c)}
$$

For example, let $I$ be the integral
$$
I=\int_0^{t_b}
\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar(t_b-t_c)}\right)^{3/2}
\exp\left(\frac{imR_{bc}^2}{2\hbar(t_b-t_c)}\right)
\exp\left(-\frac{ip^2t_c}{2m\hbar}\right)
\,dt_c
$$

Let
\begin{align*}
f(t_c)&=\left(\frac{m}{2\pi i\hbar(t_b-t_c)}\right)^{3/2}
\\
g(t_c)&=\frac{m R_{bc}^2}{2(t_b-t_c)}-\frac{p^2t_c}{2m}
\\
\lambda&=\frac{1}{\hbar}
\end{align*}

The phase of the exponential is stationary ($g'(c)=0$) for
$$
c=t_b-\frac{mR_{bc}}{p}
$$

Hence
$$
I\approx\left(\frac{2\pi i}{\lambda|g''(c)|}\right)^{1/2}
f(c)\exp(i\lambda g(c))
$$